# Android native api not working

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a project that is implemented for native Android and is integrated with Worklight server adapters.

The problem is I'm trying to integrate the Worklight Android native API in the project; I created a native API locally deployed it on the server then modified the .properties file, but I couldn't connect the server in any way.

> UNEXPECTED_ERROR Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again.

Comment: Please  mention the **error** you're getting in LogCat. You also did not really explain if you followed the instructions provided in the Worklight tutorials for native Android.

Comment: @IdanAdar sorry, I added the error to the question, and yes I did follow the tutorials on Worklight for native Android.

Comment: Upload your Android project somewhere, like Dropbox, so it could be inspected.

Comment: @IdanAdar I can't upload the project, it's not a personal one.

Comment: If you can't provide anything there is nothing for me to tell you other than that you're doing it wrong and you need to start over with the tutorial. How do you expect people to help you? Remove from the project information that is confidential.

Comment: @IdanAdar here is the project https://www.dropbox.com/s/non85i5ejtrb695/AndroidNativeAPI.zip?dl=0, but without the right wlServerContext and wlServerHost in the wlclient.properties file, I'm adding it right on my project, can you please tell me what could be wrong?

Comment: I will look at it in the morning.

Comment: @IdanAdar okay waiting for you, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attempting to use your provided project there were many Gradle errors I could not overcome. Instead I have:

1. Followed these instructions to create a new Android project and add the MFP SDK to it:  https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/hello-world/creating-first-native-android-mobilefirst-application/
2. Added the code snippets provided here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-native-android-development-7-0/quick-start-demonstration/

I was able to connect to the server, invoke the adapter and see the result in the Android Studio log.

Should be noted that in your project, you are missing the bcprov.jar file in the libs folders as well.

Comment: Actually the staging server version is 6.1 and I'm following this tutorial http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_copying_native_api_files_for_android.html?lang=en so there's no bcprov.jar in this tutorial and it's not generated in the 6.1 server

Comment: Doesn't matter; the instructions are the same.

Comment: it is working locally and I am connecting successfully to the server but when I change the configuration to make it connect to the server I get the error, please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure the wlapp file is deployed in the remote server; make sure the protocol/host/port/context are correct.

Comment: the protocol is HTTPS so I'm removing the port as mentioned in the tutorial, context and host are right because they are the same in the iOS app and they are working.

Comment: No tutorial by IBM tells you to remove the port. Put the correct port value.

Comment: Here is the a quote from 6.1 documentation: "The port of the Worklight Server. If you leave this value blank, the default port is used. If the wlServerProtocol property value is https, you must leave this value blank." and it worked on iOS

Comment: And I'm telling to put the port value and check if it works; last time I'm asking.

Comment: it worked, I changed the port value to 443. I just followed the documentation which it said that if I'm using the HTTPS then I should leave the port value blank. Thank you very much for your help.